# How can I get the parameter ID in a pytest fixture?

Tags: pytest, fixtures

Is it possible to get the parameter `ID` in a Pytest fixture?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(
     params = ['a', 'b', 'c'],
     ids    = ['x', 'y', 'z'])
def foo(request):
   myParam = request.param
   myID    = "How do I get the current ID?"
```

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is passing the ID along *as a parameter*:

```
import pytest

params = ['a', 'b', 'c']
ids    = ['x', 'y', 'z']
@pytest.fixture(params=zip(params,ids), ids=lambda x: x[1])
def foo(request):
    myParam = request.param[0]
    myID    = request.param[1]
```

This is ugly, but it works.

Comment: A couple of adjustments to @ajwood's answer (pytest==5.3.2): 1. remove the colon from the @pytest.fixture(...) line. 2. change `id` to `ids` from the @pytest.fixture(...) line.